# How to load and search data using edmx

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

[image]

I am trying to load the data into a dropdownlist in a nested master page but the Model in View is always null. How can I do this?

In model

```
 public class AllInOneModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<City> cities { get; set; }

}
```

In controller

```
public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return View(new AllInOneModel());
    }
```

In View

```
@model  IBilik.Models.AllInOneModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.City,(SelectList)Model.cities)
```

Comment: You need to add some more context... at least how is your controller action and view looks like?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would skip the "AllInOneModel" and stick to sending the single city to the view.

The controller action could look somewhat like this.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //TODO: get current cities from database
    List<City> cities = new List<City>
    {
        new City { CityID = 1, CityName = "City1" },
        new City { CityID = 2, CityName = "City2" },
        new City { CityID = 3, CityName = "City3" }
    };

    // Create the list of selectlistitems to populate the dropdown
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach(var c in cities)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = c.CityID.ToString(), Text = c.CityName });
    }

    //Throw them into viewbag
    ViewBag.ListItems = listItems;

    //TODO get some city (perhaps from db) to send to view
    var city = new City { CityID = 1, CityName = "City1" };  

    return View(city);
}
```

And then you would render the view in this way.

```
@model IBilik.Models.City

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, ViewBag.ListItems as List<SelectListItem>)
```